# How to automatically create buttons for each method in a class?

Tags: java

I want to have a list of objects with different objects.

I want a super class that has an abstract `getOptions()` method. Then I can create subclasses of the super class and when you select a object of the subclass it will make buttons for each option of in the subclass.

I want to be able to choose the options buttons will be made for. Like if I made a subclass that represented a file it would have two options like open and edit and the program would automatically make a open and edit button, but it also needs to support other subclasses that have different options and the program would make buttons for them instead.

It don't matter if it's a button, I just wanna know how I can get a list of all options in a subclass.

Comment: Everybody appreciates your effort in keeping the code blocks very condensed. but ```abstract getOptions()``` is not really enough to understand what you want to do.

Comment: It depends on how you define what an "option" is. You might use reflection if you have a naming convention, like JavaBeans. You return a list of actions and handlers. Who knows, we don't even know what framework you're using.

Comment: getOptions would be a method that returns all the options in the subclass like a file subclass would return edit and open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the child class return an instance of an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) instead.  The actions can be put into a menu or toolbar as needed to form `JMenuItem` and `JButton` instances.

Comment: And I thought he uses SWT... :)

Comment: But do I then need to make a new AbstractAction class for every single option?

Comment: Yep.  But look on the bright side.  That's why they pay us 'the big bucks'. ;)

Comment: So I know this work but hope that java reflection will make it easier

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `Option` class and hold just a `List<Option>` variable in your entity classes like file and whatever...

But maybe I did misunderstand what you really want.

Comment: No you totally understand what I want but I do not know how I build the Option class, because every Option class must have a different method and how do I return this method

Answer (score 0):

If you want list of your objects' methods or properties you can use **Java Reflection**. However I'm not sure if this is the best solution to implement your idea.